# Maven Lifecycle and Plugin

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I am currently writing a Maven Mojo that generates a class for the user so they don't have to create it manually (the class is essentially just boilerplate and my plugin fills in the information needed). The problem I am running into though is that in order to create the generated class, I need to scan the project classes for certain annotations. But the Maven `generate-sources` phase comes before the `process-classes` phase. So in order for my generated source to actually get compiled, I need to run install twice which is something I would really like to avoid.

If there is anymore information I can provide that would be useful let me know and Ill give you the details! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes please give us more details by editing the original post.